# need to convert char to cell array

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, cell

Hi I have the following object in matlab:

```
class(data{1}) =

    char
```

which is stored in

```
class(data) =

    cell
```

however I am trying to call:

```
[estt,este]  = hmmtrain(data{1},e,t);
```

and get an error:

```
??? Error using ==> hmmtrain at 209
Seqs must be cell array or numerical array.
```

Is there a way to make each element of **data** compatible with the hmmtrain function?

thanks very much

Comment: Have you tried just saying data(1) instead?

Comment: if the char in `data1` are numbers then convert to a numerical array using `str2num(data{1})`...

Comment: @natan I have tried that, but get: Warning: 'CCCCCCCCCCCCHHCCHCCCCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHCCCCCHHHHHHCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCHCCCCHHHHHHHHCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCHHHHHHHCCCCCCCCCCHEEEEEECCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCHEEEEEECCHHHHHHHHHCCCCCCCCCCCCCCHEHH' 
 exceeds the MATLAB maximum name length of 63 characters and will be truncated to 
 'CCCCCCCCCCCCHHCCHCCCCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHCCCCCHHHHHHCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHH'. 
> In str2num>protected_conversion at 80
  In str2num at 46

is there a way to override this?

Comment: it looks like you don't have numbers but letters. you need to write this in your question as well as other info regarding `data`, i.e. (size(data{1})) etc. so we can understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sequence, `data{1}` is a char array, so convert each character into it's ASCII code via `double`:

```
[estt,este]  = hmmtrain(double(data{1}),e,t);
```

If you want to feed `hmmtrain` multiple sequences with the option of using a cell array for the first input argument (as it looks like you many want to with `data` being a cell) try the following,

```
dataNumCell = cellfun(@double,data,'UniformOutput',false);
[estt,este]  = hmmtrain(dataNumCell,e,t);
```

EDIT: Updated multiple sequence option where hmmtrain had extra double.